How to export a static getter in a class?
I want to export the getter function newInstance so I don't have to do User.newInstance.
// user.ts
class User {
  name: string = ''
  static get newInstance() {
    return new User()
  }
}

export const { newInstance } = User

In other TypeScript files, when I invoke the getter function, they actually return the same instance.

import { newInstance } from './user'
const user1 = newInstance
user1.name = 'roy1'
const user2 = newInstance
user2.name = 'roy2'

// This prints: { user1: User { name: 'roy2' }, user2: User { name: 'roy2' } }
console.log({user1, user2})

What is the correct way to do it?

In other files you don't invoke the getter function.

This isn't possible, unfortunately. You'll need to just export/import something that holds the getter.  Getters only make sense as properties, not as variables. See linked q/a for more info.

Forget the word "class". The classes are one of the basic concepts of OOP, your code is not OOP at all. It is just a convoluted procedural code. Getters, setters and accessing the object properties directly (because they are public) violate one of the basic principles of OOP: encapsulation. Avoid them. Static members are not OOP either. They are just global variables or functions with fancy names. Unfortunately, [so] is not the right place to learn OOP and there aren't OOP tutorials that teach OOP the right way. :-(
